# Lower bound for $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1} $

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, inequality, approximation, upper-lower-bounds

Does anyone know any useful lower bound for $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1} $ for $x>1$. I have a problem where I want to find a lower bound for $$\sqrt{C \log(n)} - \sqrt{C \log(n)-1}  $$ for a positive constant C and $n$ large enough.

Edit: Sorry for not being precise, a lower bound as a function of $x$.

Comment: $0$ is a lower bound and is the limit as $x \to \infty$

Comment: A bounding function in terms of $x$, or a global bound? The difference approaches zero, so.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note rationalizing the numerator gives $\left(\sqrt{C \log(n)} - \sqrt{C \log(n)-1}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{C \log(n)} + \sqrt{C \log(n)-1}}{\sqrt{C \log(n)} + \sqrt{C \log(n)-1}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C \log(n)} + \sqrt{C \log(n)-1}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in a comment,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1}
&=(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1})\dfrac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-1}
}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-1}
}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-1}
}\\
&\gt \dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}\\
\end{array}
$

Using the generalized binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{1-x}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\frac12}{n}(-x)^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac12-k)}{n!}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-2k)}{2^nn!}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k-1)}{2^nn!}x^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)}{2^nn!}x^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)}{2^nn!\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)}x^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(2n-2)!}{2^nn!2^{n-1}(n-1)!}x^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}x^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n-2}{n-1}\dfrac{1}{n2^{2n-1}}x^n\\
&=1-\frac12 x-\frac18 x^2-\frac1{16}x^3-...\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}
&=\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{1-\frac1{x}})\\
&=\sqrt{x}(\frac1{2 x}+\frac1{8 x^2}+\frac1{16x^3}+...)\\
&=\frac1{2 \sqrt{x}}+\frac1{8 x\sqrt{x}}+\frac1{16x^2\sqrt{x}}+...\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}(\frac1{2}+\frac1{8 x}+\frac1{16x^2}+...)\\
\end{array}
$

You can stop the series
at any desired term
to get a lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. $$\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt x\left(1-\sqrt{1-1/x}\right).$$
It's easy to see with a little calculus (Mean Value Theorem) that $$1-\sqrt{1-t}\ge ct\quad(t\to0)$$and there you are.

Answer (score 1):

There would be many ways to bound this, for e.g. recognising that this can be written as the integral of a convex function, the rather well known [Hermite–Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) gives

$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}=\int_{x-1}^x\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}} \geqslant \frac1{\sqrt{4x-2}}$$

For deciding which bound is better to use, we need more criteria/ conditions.